# JSONP Cross-domain Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I need your help once again i was trying to make an Cross-domain request with ajax code:

```
function foo() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    });
    $.ajax({
       url:"http://www.website.com/page.php",
       type: "GET",
       crossDomain: true, // enable this
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success:function(result){

       }
    });
}
```

And this is simple html button

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="foo()">
```

When i run the function the result is that:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Sorry for my bed english and thanks in advice fou our help.

Comment: What if you use dataType: "JSON" instead of "JSONP"

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/dd64216951937866206b646cdce74182.png @mkaatman

Comment: CORS and JSONp don't go together. it's not supporting jsonp obviously, so what about just cors?

Comment: Well, the server returns JSON, whereas you tell jQuery to expect JSONP. That can't work. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` has to be set by the **server**, not the client. Similarly you can only use JSONP if the server supports it. So the first step for you should be to find out what the server supports.

Comment: @dandavis Sorry but i don't understand, if i don't use jsop it doesn't work.. if i try with cURL could work?

Comment: @terzi_matte: Obviously it doesn't work with JSONP either.

Comment: @felix Kling Server is not mine, that is the problem

Comment: Sure, but if they have a proper API documentation, they should list the formats and ways they support to access the service. If they don't allow to access the server via Ajax (i.e. they don't enable CORS or support JSONP), then you have to create your own server and use it as a proxy to connect to their server. That's simply the security model for Ajax: You can only make Ajax requests to your own server, unless other servers explicitly allow access via Ajax or provide alternative ways to access the service (e.g. via JSONP, which is not Ajax).